# Get all url in class by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, performance, class, hyperlink

I want to get all the links in the class tag like the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQLOy.png)

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div'):
      url_video = a.get_property('href')
      print(url_video)
```

i get the result is none
I use the 'a' tag to get all the links. I just want to get the links in the specified class. Please help me

This my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(6)
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div')

for element in elements:
    videoUrl = element.get_attribute('href')
    print(videoUrl)
```

----> The result is none

Answer (score 0):

`.find_elements_by_xpath()` return a list, you should use `element['href']` on each element of the list.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('...')
for element in elements:
    videoUrl = element['href']
    print(videoUrl)
```

Comment: I tried it but the result is "None"
this is my code:

from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(6)
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div')
for element in elements:
    videoUrl = element.get_attribute('href')
    print(videoUrl)



----> The result is none

Comment: i got wrong xpath. Thank you for answering the question. Love you so much